# Why does my magmatic dynamo keep stopping?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I have an ender-thermic pump set up connected to a magmatic dynamo:

[image]

It works as expected, once started with a bucket of lava in the dynamo-the pump powers the dynamo, and the dynamo powers the pump.

Periodically, it just...stops.  The lava production ceases.  The dynamo does not run out of energy, yet somehow appears to be the cause, as breaking and replacing the dynamo restarts the system.

I know there was a precursor to this device: the [magmatic engine](http://ftbwiki.org/Magmatic_Engine), which apparently overheated quite easily.  However, the [corresponding page for the magmatic *dynamo*](http://ftbwiki.org/Magmatic_Dynamo), which I'm using, mentions nothing of that sort.

I've read that the ender-thermic pump is supposed to load the chunk it's on automatically, which brings up the question of whether the dynamo is being unloaded by accidentally straddling a chunk boundary.  It is not:

[image]

Those red lines indicate the chunk boundaries, and my entire setup is within the cobblestone structure you see, which is clearly all in a single chunk.

What's going on here?  A bug? Undocumented overheating?

Comment: Where's the dynamo's input?

Comment: @JonK There isn't one.  I start it manually with a bucket of lava and it takes the rest of the lava it needs straight from the pump.  I am sure the dynamo is not running out of fuel or energy.  The internal energy buffer remains completely full even in its broken state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My earlier assumption that the dynamo was not running out of lava was apparently incorrect.  Usually the dynamo pulled it's lava from the pump, but sometimes, the dynamo seemed to stop powering the pump (despite having a completely full energy reserve) until it got more lava.  Which it wasn't going to get from an unpowered pump...

The solution? A simple redundant lava input.

[image]

---

<sup>Now granted this is all supposition up to this point and I can't really test this solution thoroughly because it's an unpredictable problem but it seems to be working so far...</sup>

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the problem is with the chunks loading and unloading or its just that the dynamo is running out of lava. Try placing a spot loader on the dynamo! The pump only loads the area where its pupming and the chunk that the pump is placed in!
Also check if the pump and the dynamo are on a chunk boundry and the pump just isnt loading the dynamo.

Comment: I'm positive the dynamo is not running out of lava, and I'm *fairly* sure it's in the same chunk as the pump, but I will check.

Comment: I have updated my question with a picture of the chunk boundaries around my setup.  As you can see, they are all within the same chunk.